# Pella Window screens

Tags: screens

I am trying to replace two Pella window screens but cannot seem to find any frame in the proper champagne color. The screens are missing so I do not have frames. Pella will not sell any of their frame. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to get the right frame?

Comment: If you need factory-made mounted screens, find a friendly contractor who does window installation; they may be able to order parts from Pella that consumers can't. But usually what people do is just mount new screen fabric in existing frames...

Comment: To add to what @keshlam said, if the frames aren't damaged your local hardware store will replace the screen fairly inexpensively.

Comment: If you are replacing the existing screen, then the existing frame must still be in good condition. If not replace the screen and frame.

Comment: If the screens are in good shape you might be able to get a local guy to re-screen them.

Comment: Pella won't sell them?   I find that hard to believe.  They may charge an astronomical amount but they would still sell them.   How old are the windows?   Do they have a number etched in the lower right corner?